# row is not getting added to table

Tags: c#, dataset

```
DataSet datare=new dataset1(); //global variable  

public partial class main_inherit : sphynx
{         
    public main_inherit():base(@"Data Source=PC5;Initial Catalog=clinic_Main;User ID=sa")
    {
    }
    string constr;
    public override SqlDataReader getval(string query)
    {
        constr = base.connector();
        try
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            sqlask = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
            rdr = sqlask.ExecuteReader();


        }
        catch { }
        sqlcon.Close();
        return rdr;
    }

    public virtual void  filldata(string text)
    {
        Form2 datare=new Form2();
        DataRow dr=datare.ds.Tables["details"].NewRow();

        dr["id"] = base.valueofstr("select patientid from master_bill1 where transactid='" + text + "' ","patientid");
        dr["name"] = base.valueofstr("select name from cust_det where id='"+dr["id"]+"'", "name");
        dr["billno"] = datare.textBox1.Text;
        dr["paidate"] = base.valueofstr
            ("select paidate from master_bill1 where transactid='"+text+"'","paidate");

        datare.ds.Tables["details"].ImportRow(dr);                
    }
}
```

The row is not getting added to the table for displaying crystal report can someone help me please I've tried to view the table in gridview its also showing empty rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
datare.ds.Tables["details"].ImportRow(dr);
```

Is not doing anything. To quote [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),

*"If the DataRow that is passed as a parameter is in a detached state, it is ignored, and no exception is thrown."*

Detatched means that it hasn't been added to a DataTable. Probably, you don't want `ImportRow` at all, use Add instead on the row collection of the table.

```
datare.ds.Tables["details"].Rows.Add(dr);
```

Basically, `ImportRow` is for copying an existing row and appending it to the table, not adding a new one.

Comment: first of all thanku steve for replying ........ i ve tried rows.add but the issue remains the same

Comment: Hard to see from your code what's going on. You refer to the dataset on an instance of `Form2`, and there's also a global variable called `datare` which is a dataset. Do you mean to use the global variable `datare` instead of the `ds` field on `Form2`?